# Can I hook a 3.5mm jack to the USB ports on the Xbox 360 to receive sound?

Tags: xbox-360

Would it be possible, with some type of wiring, to hook a 3.5mm jack to the USB ports on the Xbox and receive in-game sound?

Comment: I don't think it is possible... What type of video output are you using? Depending on that, you could fork/clone the audio part.

Comment: See also: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/21859/4163

Comment: I currently have an hdmi to dvi adapter sticking halfway out of the hdmi port on the xbox so i can play it on my monitor. I have also heard that you can simultaniously run the av out and the hdmi to overcome this, but there is no way to fit bot in there without breaking one, something i dont want to do. I have found the pinout of that port, but I don't know how to wire that to a 3.5 jack either mostly because I am worried about frying the earbuds I plan to use.

Comment: I think the problem is going to be that there are no drivers on the 360 for piping audio to a USB device.

Comment: Which Xbox are you using? I have an arcade at my house, and in order to hook up HDMI to my tv and component to my home theater system, I took off the plastic wrapper part of the component connector(easily done with a flathead screwdriver) so both connectors could be plugged in simultaneously. If your component cable connector has a big plastic cover on it, I would suggest prying it off if you wish to use HDMI/Component at the same time. It can be put back together very easily if you want to have it in it's original state at a later time.

Answer (score 5):

No

A headphone connected through a 3.5mm jack is expecting an analog signal. The USB port sends a digital signal and needs to talk through the USB protocol. As mentioned on a different answer, a few companies make converters to handle this for you. I'm also partial to Turtle Beach.

Answer (score 4):

How about picking up a cable like [this Xbox 360 VGA HD AV Cable](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/Xbox360/Accessories/CablesNetworking/Xbox360GVGSHDCable) and an RCA to 3.5mm adapter for the audio?

Comment: I thought about it, and I already have an rca adapter, but the only price I found agreeable was used in store gamestop, and every time I go, they are all sold out.  I was hoping to be able to match up some xbox pins to some 3.5 mm pins.

Comment: @asandwhich, simply not possible, see Perishable Dave's post below.

Answer (score 2):

Creative Labs recently release the first commercial external sound card for all 3 major consoles called [Recon3D](http://www.creative.com/soundblaster/recon3d/recon3d/). It is very expensive at over $100 USD, but it is packed full of technology to improve the sound output. It is a very good solution but damn it's expensive.

Comment: I don't like Creative very much because of their driver support and their bling bling UI and marketing bogus, and it got even worse when I moved to Linux... BUT looking at the wiring, they do what everyone else had trouble with: processing optical 5.1 audio. Definitely worth looking into this, especially since some next generation consoles might drop analog/component outputs. http://support.creative.com/kb/ShowArticle.aspx?sid=96619

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a head set for game audio, USB isn't the way to go. I'm pretty sure the Xbox 360 doesn't support audio over USB, only via the ports on the back.

There are a variety of third party headsets on the market that handle both in-game audio and voice chat over Xbox Live. I'm partial to Turtle Beach, but there are other great ones out there as well. Most have setup instructions for hooking the headset directly to the console, or through the TV/receiver.

Answer (score 0):

If your TV/stereo/entertainment system (or whatever you have set up to play the XBox' audio through speakers) also has RCA out, like mine does, you can hook up your headphones to that with an RCA/minijack adaptor. It works great  for late-night gaming when you don't want to wake the neighbours.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.gamestop.com/xbox-360/accessories/xbox-360-hd-and-analog-av-adaptor/90329?affid=9797&cid=ppc_60000001

That worked for me :)

Comment: Can you provide a better link or (even better) a description of the item you're trying to link to? Gamestop is one of those annoying sites that breaks direct linking to products.

Comment: don't right click just click on it. Its an XBox 360 HD and Analog AV Adaptor.

Comment: Ironically, clicking the link redirects me to a "choose your site" page, but right-clicking works.